# how to create client account id from another user type

Tags: django, django-3.0

hi I trying to implement multiple user type in django , I have one-to-one relation between the account model and the client model  it's not working the , I don't know how to get the user from the Account user to the Client user I got this error('Client' object has no attribute 'id') any solution, please.

models.py :

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,full_name=None,password=None , is_active=True,is_staff=False,is_admin=False):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an password ')

        user_object = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name=full_name,


        )

        user_object.set_password(password)
        user_object.staff =is_staff
        user_object.admin = is_admin
        user_object.active = is_active

        user_object.save(using=self._db)
        return user_object

    def create_client(self,salary,email,password,full_name=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name=full_name,
            password=password,

        )

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_staffuser(self, email,e, password,full_name=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name =full_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password,full_name=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name = full_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff = True,
            is_admin = True,
        )

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # a superuser

    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that is built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


    objects = AccountManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        if self.full_name:
            return self.full_name
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.active


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,parent_link=True)
    salary = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=50,decimal_places=2)



    objects = AccountManager()



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

forms.py :

```
class RegisterClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password.
    """
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    salary = forms.DecimalField( max_digits=50, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('salary',)

    def clean_slary(self):
        salary = self.cleaned_data.get('salary')
        return salary

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(RegisterClientForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.password = self.cleaned_data["password1"]
        # user.id = User.objects.get(id=user.id) => the problem is here ?
        user.active = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py :

```
def signup_client(request):
    form = RegisterClientForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # form.client_save()
        form.save()
```

Comment: You are messing with your multiple users logic. Simple create user then make client model with onetoone field. First you need to login/sign up the user after that you have login user id then save client salary. How we can save anonymous user data?

Comment: i already sign up and login a user , whene i save i get a new user in the accounts table , the user is already login

Comment: If you already login and have also account why are u saving client details in sign up view?

Comment: Instead of user.id only write user and assign user instance. And also check which kind of user you are fetching and assign to client object.

Comment: its just and exemple i trying to implement multiple user type , that why i added the salary attribute